# How can I separately control two embedded iframe youtube videos?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

so my end goal is to have two video players on top of each other, when one nears the end it fades down volume, and sets the div of the underlying video to be on top which then fades volume up with a new video.

I can successfully control the youtube player with the api but I dont know where to begin when say I want to wait for specifically the first players start event and not just any players start event.

any ideas?

for example how do i get this function to distinguish between both players?

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow of the YouTube Iframe API is as follows:

1. Load YouTube API.
2. When loaded, the global `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` method is called.
3. In this method, a wrapper is created to interact with a framed YouTube player.

The `onPlayerReady` method in your question is a part of step 3. Before I continue, I show a part of [the example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) from the official documentation.

```
// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
   player = new YT.Player('player', {
      // ...
      events: {
         'onReady': onPlayerReady // <-------
      // ...
```

In this example, you clearly see that **you** are binding the `onPlayerReady` function to a specific event. To act differently for two players, you can simply use different functions.

```
player1 = new YT.Player('id_of_player1', {
    events: {
       'onReady': onPlayerReady1
    } // ...
};
player2 = new YT.Player('id_of_player2', {
    events: {
       'onReady': onPlayerReady2
    } // ...
};
```

Comment: that's a lot easier then I expected! Thank you!